# Why did the LaTeX proposal enter beta before Ubuntu?

Tags: support, area-51

I can't figure out why LaTeX went into private beta an hour ago, when the Ubuntu proposal had far more commitments and referrals.

Any reason for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beta sites wont always be launched in the order they reach 100% progress. Sometimes there will be technical, social, or resource issues that need to be worked out. The site gets launched as soon as it's ready.

The LaTeX proposal was pretty cut and dried; ready to launch. So we launched it. There has been a bit of discussion around the Ubuntu proposal of whether it should be merged with the more general Linux/Unix site. We're looking at whether more needs to be done to make sure the community is getting what they want or is it really ready to go.

Comment: Well, if you want my opinion, the Ubuntu proposal likely became popular **because** it was exclusively about Ubuntu. I think a lot of people would uncommit from the proposal if you merged it with the Linux proposal. A more general site would be of less use to me, for example.

Comment: But thanks for answering the question. Know we know a bit more about how the process works.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. I thought each proposal stood or fell on its own support - i.e. amount of commitment, interest and activity. A proposal for Ubuntu is a proposal for ubuntu, a proposal for Linux is a propsal for Linux - no? I understand 'technical' and 'resource' but ' social' sounds like there is some second guessing behind the scenes about which proposals should move forward compared to others, based on considerations other than what is publicly voted on/supported. Someone enlighten me?

Comment: @mickeyf: As a for-instance of other 'social' factors behind the scenes:  They also need to consider SE 1.0 sites that may be related-to/impacted-by a SE 2.0 site proposal at area51.  See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange under *What if a new, community-created site competes with my existing, old-rules Stack Exchange?*

Comment: @mickeyf: It's sounds like you're saying we should never doubt or check on the results of the (beta) system we *just* built? We took half a day to ask some of the participants *"Is this what you intended?"* The answer was "yes," we moved on. Nothing to see here.

Answer (score 4):

Jeff said there are more factors than "progress", for example, percentage of overlap of committers to other proposals, which would make it difficult for them to actively participate.

Comment: So it's basically anyone's guess what the next proposal to enter private beta will be?

Comment: +1 for pointing out overlap. I'm actually glad that the LaTeX proposal and the Ubuntu proposal didn't enter beta at the same time because I'm committed to both (and I'm far from being the only one).